# Writing two column paragraph with fixed tabulation

Tags: two-column

I want to write a text like in the figure I uploaded. It seems like a basic question but I have trouble finding an appropriate answer. Basically, I just want a descriptive a text after each symbol with an exact tabulation in each paragraph. I also want the paragraph at the right to be well justified. DO you have a trick for that???????? I tried the `multicol` package but it's not pretty.

Thanks,
Eric.

[image: Text]

Comment: `\usepackage{enumitem}` and `\begin{enumerate}[label={\Alph*}] \item Text one \item Text two...\end{enumerate}`, for example

Comment: good idea, but I have two questions, how do I control: the tabulation (space between the two columns) and what I write in (A B C...  thanks!

Comment: See the answer and the screen shot please

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an enumeration with letter counter, i.e. `\Alph` for me!
The separation between the label and the text can be changed with `labelsep=...` (see the example below)

The `enumerate` environment does the labelling automatically.

Please note that is does only allow for 26 items at most, since `\Alph` is used as counter formatter, so the range is limited within `A`...`Z`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\Alph*},labelsep=20pt]
  \item \blindtext
  \item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I want, but I want to write something else instead of A B C... how do I do this????

Comment: What is `else` instead of  ABC? Your screen shot shows ABC, therefore I assumed precisely this numbering scheme

Comment: Other letters, precisely, mathematical symbols. I want to define a mathematical formalism. they are little symbols, max two characters!

Comment: @Eric: That was not clear from your question :-(

Comment: yes I know. I wanted the general layout. your solution is perfect for it, if I can switch the symbols to my wishes!

Comment: @Eric: Use the `description` environment instead and `\item[YourSymbol]` yourtext \item[YourotherSymbol] .... `